# How do i navigate to httpd_vhosts.conf in xammp from the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications

How do I navigate to `httpd_vhosts.conf` in Xammp from the terminal?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45518021/where-to-find-htdocs-in-xampp-mac) was all I could find on the subject.

Comment: What do you mean "navigate to"?

Comment: cd /some/path/to/vhosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need 3 directories to configure Xammp on OSX.

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
/etc/hosts
```

you can open file from within the terminal for editing using e.g. `nano`

```
nano /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

you can then edit it and save changes using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: Thats what i wanted, I was getting hung up in /Users/tristanisthebomb/Applications/Xammp which was empty!